# Bash Variables not working in R Markdown

Tags: r, bash, shell, r-markdown, knitr

I'm using a chunk of bash code in my R Markdown document (.Rmd).

A minimal example looks like this:

````
```{bash}
MY_NAME='Fred'
echo $MY_NAME
```
````

When I knit this, I get no output, meaning, the variable is not recognized.

When I do the same in my Unix console, it outputs 'Fred'. Any hint as to why the variable doesn't seem to be stored?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error on a Mac, see [this file](https://github.com/dewittpe/so/blob/accdae7091dc418cd982defac324d3c060631425/50156025/so.Rmd) for the .Rmd file.

Comment: I downloaded your entire folder, and tried to reproduce your output by running the render.R file (I removed the pdf output). Anyhow, I get an empty bash output, also for your file.

could anybody running WSL confirm this problem?

Comment: Here's my failed reproduction of your failed reproduction: xP

https://github.com/MichaelBeyeler/BashProblemRMarkdown